# Pursue a profession or pursue a career?

Tags: business-language

Is "pursuing" a valid way to ask for a persons work situation?
When I googled it, I found "pursue a career" but I want to ask about his situation rather than his work goal.

Is this correct?:

*Are you pursuing a non self-employed profession?*

Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Welcome to ES&U.  Some context would be helpful.  How you ask might depend on the community--local or people with whom you are in touch in various places--to find out whether this person might be interested in a specific position or job in the organization you work for, or whether he is pursuing his career wherever he is now.

Comment: Generally speaking, profession is more about things you do than details of your employment. Career suits more here.

Comment: For me 'pursuing' is applicable to a career rather than a profession. One may _pursue_ a career as a doctor, for example, but would _practice_ the profession of medicine in doing so. The word 'pursue' implies, to me, active seeking for personal development, promotion or both; practicing, on the other hand, refers to the actual performance of the duties of the occupation  on a day to day basis.

Comment: The context here is a person requesting a loan.

I want to ask whether the person is employed or self-employed - in most cases it will be first but if the person is self-employed he or she is not qualified for the loan.

Would the following simplified questions make sense?

Are you working as an employee?
or
Are you an employee?